# XFS Resize Possible?

Tags: linux-mint, dd, xfs, nemo

Can I dd XFS home to backup drive then nuke home & resize root recreating new XFS home then dd file structure back?!?

Cannot upgrade Mint 17.3 to 18 as not enough room in root.

Would this work with a simple offline file manager copy?

Comment: for the XFS file system, you should use `xfsdump` and `xfsrestore`, and not `dd`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

freed enough space on root for upgrade. I had 1.3GB jumping to 7GB when cache cleared.